# PHP preg_split: Split string by hyphen

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-split

I want to split the string into array using PHP `preg_split` built in functions.

for example:

I have this string: `51-200 employees` and I want the results to be without `employees` string:

```
array (
  0 => '51',
  1 => '200',
)
```

Comment: Have you tried explode? http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: @ka_lin Yes, i tried and the results is array ( 0 => '51', 1 => '200 employees' ) expected one is array ( 0 => '51', 1 => '200' )

Comment: Use `preg_match_all("/\d+/", $str, $matches)`

Comment: Forgot about `preg_match_all()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only have two integers separated by a slash followed by useless characters, you can use a formatted string with [`sscanf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sscanf.php):

```
$result = sscanf('51-200 employees', '%d-%d');
```

Comment: Simple & sweet. Works like a charm. Tq.

Answer (score 2):

The php [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) split string by delimiter but you want to select digits from string. Using [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) is better.

```
$str = "51-200 employees";
preg_match_all("/\d+/", $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches[0]);
```

See result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/tJAPY)

Answer (score 0):

If the string has always the format `'<number>-<number2> employees'` you can make use of `explode()`:

```
$string = '51-200 employees';
$splittedString = explode(' ', $string);
$numbers = explode('-', $splittedString[0]);
```

Will output `array([0] => 51, [1] => 200)`.